# How to run a method with blocking behaviour in Python asyncio? Method is from tesseract library for OCR

Tags: python, tesseract, python-asyncio

I have async programm and it is necessary to run a blocking function without blocking event loop. Execution of this function takes aroud 4 seconds. Unfortunately I can`t let it block event loop for such a long time.

Code below says what I want to do.

```
image = Image.open(image_path)                                   
result = await loop.run_in_executor(None, image_to_string(image ))
```

However I am getting error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Could you tell me what is wrong with this code and how can I get desired behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it right. The problem is that [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) is a function like any other, so if you pass it `image_to_string(image)`, Python will interpret that as an instruction to **call** `image_to_string` immediately, and pass the **result** of the call to `run_in_executor`.

To avoid that interpretation, `run_in_executor` accepts a *function*, which it will call on its own, in another thread. The function is optionally followed by arguments, so the correct call looks like this:

```
result = await loop.run_in_executor(None, image_to_string, image)
```